# How to remove a special character (precisely double quotes) from the adodb recordset while exporting it to CSV in vb6?

Tags: csv, vb6

My requirement is to remove the special characters especially double quotes from the adodb recordset while exporting to CSV in VB6 using the below code.

if any double quotes is present the value after double quotes is moved to next column.

Specifically, the double quotes are present in `rsData.Fields(K).Value` not in `rsData.Fields(K).Name`. I'm not sure how to remove the double quotes in `rsData.Fields(K).Value`.

**Any help to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.**

```
'Converting the recordset 

Public Function RecordsetToCSV(rsData As ADODB.Recordset, Optional ShowColumnNames As Boolean = True, Optional NULLStr As String = "") As String
    Dim K As Long, RetStr As String
    
    If ShowColumnNames Then
        For K = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
            RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
        Next K
        
        RetStr = Mid(RetStr, 2) & vbNewLine
    End If
    
    RetStr = RetStr & """" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, -1, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
    RetStr = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 3)
    
    RecordsetToCSV = RetStr
End Function 

'Creating CSV file
    Dim CSVData As String
    CSVData = RecordsetToCSV(rsData, True)

    Open "C:\test.csv" For Binary Access Write As #1
        Put #1, , CSVData
    Close #1
```

reference : https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?481705-VB6-Save-Recordset-to-CSV-format

Comment: You don't have to use double quotes for your CSV delimiter - you could use the tab character (vbTab constant) instead - then those values will get imported correctly into their own column. In fact - just use the defaults for GetString and it will do this, as in rsData.GetString(adClipString)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes, which is done by doubling them up.

```
RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & Replace(rsData.Fields(K).Name, """", """""") & """"
```

Comment: I should have explained the problem more precisely,  the double quotes are present in "rsData.Fields(K).Value" not in rsData.Fields(K).Name, I'm not sure how to remove the double quotes in rsData.Fields(K).Value

Comment: Just apply the same technique as shown by @Kyle Swanton.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Hi, Where I'm suppose to apply the same logic? I'm using the inbuilt function GetString to get the values in I'm not looping the recordset, I dont see a place to apply this logic in the GetString function.

Comment: You can apply that logic to the resulting string. But if I were you, I'd throw away the GetString() method and retrieve each column separately, and handle it's data type appropriately, i.e. enclose contents of text/string columns in double quotes and **also** escaping double quotes _within_ the (string) data properly. Otherwise it may break your result CSV. And properly format date values so the importing application can consume them as dates, i.e. use the correct locale date format that the import (Excel?) expects.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the defaults to import the data with double quotes by using the  character as the delimiter

Change:

```
RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
```

To:

```
RetStr = RetStr & "," & vbTab & rsData.Fields(K).Name & vbTab
```

And

```
RetStr = RetStr & """" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, -1, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
```

To:

```
RetStr = RetStr & rsData.GetString(adClipString)
```

And you might have to change the last line that removes those last characters to

```
RetStr = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 2)
```

***EDIT - If you really truly feel the double quotes must be removed from your data, you can do it by using a different delimiter initially - say the squiggle "~" and then replace double quotes in one step, and the squiggle in next step***

As in:

```
RetStr = RetStr & "~" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, -1, "~")
```

Last lines would then be

```
RetStr = Replace(RetStr,"""","")    
RecordsetToCSV = Replace(RetStr,"~","""")
```

And of course remember to use the "~" in your column header loop

```
RetStr = RetStr & ",~" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & "~"
```